# Wildcard SSL on 2 Servers

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm helping an SEO client install an SSL certificate and have run into some issues. I'll try to simplify it.

He has 2 servers: 1. SERVER A: Internal server running IIS that contains chat and support software. It has to be hosted on IIS.

SERVER B: External server running Apache 2.2 that hosts the website.
I have a wildcard SSL cert installed on SERVER B, with 2 a records: "chat.serverb.com" and "support.serverb.com"...

The internal server has an ip address and the directories /chat and /SupportSoftware.

I should also mention that SERVER B is a VPS but I only have access to the cPanel.

I wanted to create vhosts in Apache and I believe that would've worked, but I don't have access to do that. I thought I could throw it into the .htaccess file but that gave me 500 server errors.

As of right the Chat and Support software doesn't work since they need to be running as https, so this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

This feels like a huge mess at this point and over my head, so I'm trying to get some ideas of what my options might be.

Comment: Ditch cPanel. It's an atrocity. After doing that, you'll be free to make the necessary modifications to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really an option at this point. Otherwise I'd love to.

Comment: That's what you're going to need to do if you want help here. cpanel and the like mess up your server so badly and make it impossible to manage in a sane manner, that we don't take questions that involve them.

Comment: On Server A (IIS version ?) - have you uploaded the certificate in IIS Manager, then bind the site with the certificate? On Server B (Apache 2.2) - have you uploaded the certificate using cPanel SSL/TLS Manager?

Comment: Tim, yes on cPanel I have installed the Wildcard SSL and it's working properly.